# Redshift SQL - Running Sum using Unbounded Proceding and Following

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

When we use the window function to calculate the running sum like `SUM(sales) over (partition by dept order by date)`, if we don't specify the range/window, is the default setting as **between unbounded proceding and current row**, basically from the first row until the current row?

According to [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Window_function_synopsis.html) it seems to be the case, but I wanted to double check.

Thanks!

Comment: The documentation is correct.  The only nuance is that it is `range between` not `rows between` so duplicate may not quite work as expected.

Comment: @GordonLinoff so if there is duplicate, I guess just need to use the primary key or any unique key in the order by to solve this issue?

Comment: Or just use an explicit `rows between unbounded preceding and current row`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are running into is 'what does the database engine assume in ambiguous circumstances?'  I've run into this exact case before when porting from SQLserver to Redshift - SQL server assumes that is you order but don't specify a frame that you want unbounded preceding to current row.  Other DBs do not make the same assumption - if you don't specify a frame it will be unbounded preceding to unbounded following and yet other will throw an error if you specify and "order by" but don't specify a frame.  Bottom line - don't let the DB engine guess what you want, be specific.

Gordon is correct that this is based on rows, not ranges.  If you want a running sum by date (not row), you can group by date and run the window function - windows execute after group by in a single query.